# Compartir datos entre proyectos Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

Buena tarde!! tengo una pregunta-duda ojala me puedan ayudar.

Saben si hay alguna forma de compartir datos de variables a otros proyectos o entre diferentes modulos que pertenece a un proyecto. Es decir, tengo mi proyecto principal y de ese una variable la cual quiero pasarla a un modulo para realizar una operación.

Lei que con SharedPreferences con `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`pero esta opción ya esta obsoleta espero me haya explicado.

Comment: Compartir información entre app, ya no está permitido, por temas de seguridad, etc como viste antes sharedPreferend tenía aquella opccion pero ya está en offline. Y no puedes volver a general aquella variable nuevamente ?

Comment: Buen día!! lo que pasa que valor de la variable es dinámico, y ese valor lo quiero pasar un modulo en la cual también estoy trabajando.

Comment: puedes usar un WS para compartir informacion

Comment: es vdd muchas gracias!! pensaba usar SQLite no se si sea posible hacer lo antes mencionado

Comment: Si deseas compartir entre diferentes móviles, no podras usar SqlLIte, recuerda que esata bd es solo local